# Java java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index on preparing statement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, sqlexception

my code below query the database for a set of rows based on user input. I have tried and tested the query inside of SQL Developer and it works perfectly fine returning the correct rows. And example of an input is : 2013-01-22

But for some reason inside of java i am getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
```

The console indicates it is firing at this line here:

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, to);
```

The full connection code:

```
ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        try {
            String strQuery =
                    "SELECT homes.home_id, homes.title, homes.description, homes.living_room_count, homes.bedroom_count, homes.bathroom_count, homes.price, homes.sqft,"
                    + " listagg(features.feature_name, '\n') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY features.feature_name) features, home_type.type_name"
                    + " FROM homes"
                    + " INNER JOIN bookings ON bookings.home_id <> homes.home_id"
                    + " INNER JOIN home_feature ON homes.home_id = home_feature.home_id"
                    + " INNER JOIN home_type ON home_type.type_code = homes.type_code"
                    + " INNER JOIN features ON home_feature.feature_id = features.feature_id"
                    + " WHERE bookings.booking_end < date '?'"
                    + " OR bookings.booking_start > date '?'"
                    + " GROUP BY homes.home_id, homes.title, homes.description, homes.living_room_count, homes.bedroom_count, homes.bathroom_count, homes.price, homes.sqft, home_type.type_name";

            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);//prepare the statement
            preparedStatement.setString(1, to);//insert
            preparedStatement.setString(2, from);//insert
            rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();//execute query
```

The full stack trace looks like this:

```
SEVERE: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setStringInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5317)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setString(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5305)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setString(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:248)
at DB.DatabaseConnector.getPropertiesSearch(DatabaseConnector.java:258)
at DB.SearchServlet.doPost(SearchServlet.java:47)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE:     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setStringInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5317)
SEVERE:     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setString(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5305)
SEVERE:     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setString(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:248)
SEVERE:     at DB.DatabaseConnector.getPropertiesSearch(DatabaseConnector.java:258)
SEVERE:     at DB.SearchServlet.doPost(SearchServlet.java:47)
SEVERE:     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
SEVERE:     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Im not quite sure why the error would be thrown as the query works fine is SQL developer. I am using Oracle

EDIT:

The result set is read into this within the same method. The homes object is then passed back:

```
HomeList homes = new HomeList();
homes = new HomeList(rs);
```

The constructor looks like this:

```
public HomeList(ResultSet rs) {
    this();
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
               list.add(new Home(rs.getInt(1),   
                                 rs.getString(2),
                                 rs.getString(3),   
                                 rs.getInt(4),
                                 rs.getInt(5),
                                 rs.getInt(6),
                                 rs.getInt(7),
                                 rs.getInt(8),
                                 rs.getString(9),
                                 rs.getString(10)
                                     ));
        }//end while
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }//end try
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you use for accessing the result set? may be your trying to select columns that don't exist in the result set!

Comment: For better help sooner,post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Everywhere inside the query string, the wildcard should be `?` instead of `'?'`. That should solve the problem.

**EDIT :**

To add to that, you need to change `date '?'` to `to_date(?, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`. Please try that and let me know.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. i tried removing the '' but the console threw a     java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: You should put spaces at the end of each row.

Comment: for java.sql.SQLException: ORA-0093, refer to this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520881/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-00936-missing-expression

Comment: @giorashc: glad that you found that

Comment: aha, thanks for your help, that work. changing to to_date(?). thanks

Answer (score 2):

As @TechSpellBound suggested remove the quotes around the ? signs. Then add a space character at the end of each row in your concatenated string. Otherwise the entire query will be sent as   (using only part of it as an example) : `.... WHERE bookings.booking_end < date ?OR bookings.booking_start > date ?GROUP BY ....`

The `?` and the `OR` needs to be seperated by a space character. Do it wherever needed in the query string.

Comment: AFAIK shorthand date casts only work with literal strings, not with parameters. Also his next line starts with a space, so the problem you describe does not actually exist.

Comment: I was referring to his example otherwise he might be confused. This was already mentioned by @TechSpellBound

Answer (score 1):

In `date '?'`, the `'?'` is a literal string with value `?`, not a parameter placeholder, so your query does not have any parameters. The `date` is a shorthand cast from (literal) string to date. You need to replace `date '?'` with `?` to actually have a parameter.

Also if you know it is a date, then use `setDate(..)` and not `setString(..)` to set the parameter.